How to get a dedication correct into .pdf-file, which is input after a title page
My dedication is compiled correctly but shows via \input{Widmung.tex} prompt the following failure. Anyone here to fix it, please? The question is part of the problem here: Migration of thesis written in \documentclass{DissOnlineLatex} to \documentclass [12pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrbook}
Edited on 17.12.2024, 13:40 CET:
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...
l.75 \input
{Widmung.tex}
?
Small example without using \input is:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrbook}
\begin {document}
\makeatletter % Diese Zeile darf nicht gesl\"oscht werden!
\title{\vspace{-3.5cm}\Huge\textbf{Zeitaufgeloeste Lumineszenzspektroskopie und Mikroskopie von Donor-Akzeptor-Hybriden}\\ 
\vspace{3.5cm}
\large{Dissertation\\ 
zur\\Erlangung des Doktorgrades (Dr. rer. nat.)\\ 
der\\
\\Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche Fakult\"at\\der\\ 
\\Rheinische Friedrich-Wilhelm Universit\"at Bonn\\
\vspace{3.5cm}}}
\author{ vorgelegt von \\ Herrn Peter Florian Zilkens\\ aus \\Mayen\\ Bern, 2025}
\date{\raggedright\normalsize{\vspace*{15cm}
Angefertigt mit Genehmigung der Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftlichen Fakult\"at der Rheinischen Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universit\"at Bonn\\
\vspace{1cm}
1. Gutachter: \\Prof. Dr. P. V\"ohringer\\
2. Gutachter: \\Prof. Dr.\\
\vspace{1cm}
Tag der Promotion: \\2025\\ }
}
\makeatother
\dedication{Im Gedenken an meine Gro{\ss}eltern} 
\clearpage
Lorem ipsum
\clearpage
\end{document}


The code as shown in your question will result in a multitude of other errors, but not reproduce the error you show.

last time I fixed your markup so code sections are in a code block but please do it on your own postes, three backticks \`` or just highlight it and use the {} button in the editor

LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end. is a simple error generated by a mis-placed \\  it is unrelated to the question in your title.

showing an error message that is not caused by the code posted does not help anyone make an answer if you want help with an error message surely it is obvious that you should post an example that makes that error.

So where is this double forward slash in my conde presented in the larger coden here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/732472/migration-of-thesis-written-in-documentclassdissonlinelatex-to-documentclass

You fixed a misspelling, but you removed the code formatting.  Don't do that.  We've already established that your other question is a mess.  Start this question with a blank project, and add pieces until you get to something that you think should work, but doesn't.  Then copy / paste that and its error message here.  Don't pretend that you're doing it but actually pasting bits from a larger file.

Sorry but I don't get it. My probelm has something to do with the combination of \input-prompt and the dedication. Since the larger code seems to be to complicated to get any help, I broke that down. Sorry but I won't write the entire thesis that I processed for years new because of a dysfunctional \document class called DissOnlineLatex. I'll imply an new blank project tomorrow then.

Please. Nobody suggested you should rewrite your thesis. what we need is for you to post code which we can copy, paste into a blank document and compile to produce the error you want help with. before posting the code, you should do the same i.e. put that code into an empty document and try to compile it to make sure it produces the error you're asking about. as it stands, your example will give errors, but it will not give the error you are asking about. the \\  is in some code you're not shown.

The first error I get with your code is: LaTeX Error: Command \dedication already defined. This is because of your \newenvironment{dedication}. See the KOMA-Script documentation (English or German one) how to use \dedication in KOMA-Script classes.

Your new code produces produces new errors like File ended while scanning use of \date, but does not reproduce the message you show. When you post something on this site, please always test it first to make sure it shows the error you are actually trying to solve. I doubt it will help you if we debug the missing } after the date and remove the \end{filecontents} which was never opened.

There is a lot in your new example, that you never should do. For example: (1) You are misusing almost all elements of the \maketitle title for something else. If you want a self-designed title, you should use the titlepage environment instead of of abusing the predefined title. (2) Font size macros like \large do not have an argument.  (3) \end{filecontents} without  a \begin{filecontents}[…]{…} does not make any sense and is a mistake (and after removing it, there is no more error message, but still no title). (4) Your usage of \makeatletter …\makeatother does not make sense.

The problem with the "There's no line to end" error (after adding \maketitle) are the two consecutive \\ in the \title argument (two times, if I've not overseen some). As already told: Never use \\ to add vertical space resp. empty lines.

@cabohah: (3) deleted. (1) & (4): the misusing stems from the old \documentclass{DissOnlineLatex}, the resulting .pdf-layout given there is prescribed by the university.

@PeterZilkens Did you test the example you now show in your question?

It works now. It's been a mixture of the \ in front of \vspace issue and one misplaced }.

KOMA-Script classes have a build in command \dedication. So you cannot use \newenvironment{dedication} to define a new environment with the same name. You could use \renewenvironment or just use the existing dedication feature documented in section 3.7 of the current KOMA-Script documentations, which are available in English and in German:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}% for demonstration only
\begin{document}
\title{Mein schönes neues Buch}
\author{Cabohah}
\dedication{Im Gedenken an meine Großeltern}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}


BTW: Are you sure you want a single sided book? Usually I would suggest to remove option oneside for books. And option a4paper is default with scrbook, so you can remove it too.
Using \input for the dedication would also work, either:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Widmung.tex}
\dedication{Im Gedenken an meine Großeltern.}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}% for demonstration only
\begin{document}
\title{Mein schönes neues Buch}
\author{Cabohah}
\input{Widmung.tex}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}

or even:
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Widmung.tex}
Im Gedenken an meine Großeltern.
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}% for demonstration only
\begin{document}
\title{Mein schönes neues Buch}
\author{Cabohah}
\dedication{\input{Widmung.tex}}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}

Results are the same as shown above.

I've implemented your code, thx for that. Failure is still persistent. Perhaps it has something to do with the prestanding title page. I deleted the last \ but nothing changed.

@PeterZilkens There is no such error neither with the code in my example(s), nor in the code of your example in the question. Sorry, but without code, that reproduces your problem, it is hard to answer your question. I can only guess: Don't use \\ when you've not already started a line, i.e., don't use \\ to try to generate vertical spaces like empty lines.

@PeterZilkens That's why we've been so annoying about you providing a MWE.  cabohah went to the trouble to make your code work, but it turns out that your problem was elsewhere.

Many apologies for your straggling. But the problem I have turned out to be very comlex and the underlying failure hard to find in a minimum example. Right now I present the full story, hopefully.

@PeterZilkens Make a copy of your project, then start removing content while checking that the error still occurs  and no other errors popped up. This way you can narrow your problem down to a MWE about which you can ask a useful question.

Many thx everybody for their discussion and help. Now the .pdf-output looks like it should -- after a one week struggle. ;-)

@PeterZilkens I hope you realize by now that you could have easily spared yourself the week-long struggle if you had provided a real, complete, minimal example that fits the problem and also taken the comments about \\ seriously.
